# AWS Lambda NetworkingError when sending and email with a Node.js handler

Tags: node.js, amazon-web-services, email, aws-lambda, amazon-ses

I am trying to send an email from a Lambda Node.js application:

**mail-service.js**

```
const ses = new aws.SES({
   region: 'eu-west-1'
});

exports.send = (to, subject, text) => {
    const deferred = Q.defer();
    const eParams = {
        Destination: {
            ToAddresses: [to]
        },
        Message: {
            Body: {
                Text: {
                    Data: text
                }
            },
            Subject: {
                Data: subject
            }
        },
        Source: to
    };
    console.log("Sending mail %s", JSON.stringify(eParams));
    const email = ses.sendEmail(eParams, function(err, data){
        if(err){
            deferred.reject(err);   
        } 
        else {
            deferred.resolve(data);
        }
    });
    return deferred.promise;
}
```

When this service is called it throws at NetworkingError:

**index.js:**

```
    mailService.send(process.env.EMAIL_TO, subject, text)
    .then( (response) => {
        console.log("SES response: %s", response);
    })
    .fail( (err) => {
        console.log("SES err: %s", err);  
    });
```

**Error:** `SNS err: NetworkingError: connect ECONNREFUSED 127.0.0.1:8000`

How can I fix it?

Notice I have configured a IAM policy associated to the lambda's role to allow sending emails:

```
{
    "Version": "2012-10-17",
    "Statement": [
        {
            "Sid": "xxxxxxxxxx",
            "Effect": "Allow",
            "Action": [
                "ses:SendEmail",
                "ses:SendRawEmail"
            ],
            "Resource": [
                "*"
            ]
        }
    ]
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem was there was a dev profile that configured AWS sdk to work with a local DynamoDB:

```
AWS.config.update({
  region: "eu-west-2",
  endpoint: "http://localhost:8000"
});
```

I removed the endpoint key and now it works.